# SQL: I need to figure out how to exclude an ID based on multiple parameters

Tags: sql, report

I'm working on a report that's goal to to pull back certain providerid based on a set of criteria. My entire report is working, except for one part of the logic. I need to exclude all providerids that have any claims that aren't closed or do not have a balance of 0. There's six total fields that (three that need to be closed, three that need to be 0) that I'm working with. My current code looks like this when trying to limit providerids:

```
and not (primaryclaimstatus != 'CLOSED'
   or secondaryclaimstatus != 'CLOSED'
   or patientclaimstatus != 'CLOSED')
and not (primaryoutstanding != 0
   or secondaryoutstanding != 0
   or patientoutstanding != 0)
```

I can't figure out how to qualify it so it only pulls back providers where ALL their claims are closed and 0. It currently seems to be pulling any provider who has ANY claims that equal 0 and are closed

Comment: Can you provide data sample and a question ?

Comment: I was able to figure it out. I had to use two common table expressions in order to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is in the fourth line, of this part of the code.
You need the providerids that have any claims that aren't closed OR do not have a balance of 0. So you should replace the "and" in the 4th line with "or".

Also you don't need to use "not". It is confusing. It is like having double denial

```
AND (primaryclaimstatus != 'CLOSED'
OR secondaryclaimstatus != 'CLOSED'
OR patientclaimstatus != 'CLOSED')
OR (primaryoutstanding != 0
OR secondaryoutstanding != 0
OR patientoutstanding != 0)
```

Comment: So the reason I have the and not in there is because I want to exclude everything that isn't Closed and 0. I'll put the full query for more context, but really I need to only pull a provider id if all their claims are closed and 0 for these six columns. If anything doesn't have closed and 0, they need to be excluded from the query:

Comment: This is a simplified version to fit the character limit, the real query has this part and more inside of a nested query:
`select distinct supervisingproviderid 
from claim c
where (c.primaryclaimstatus = 'CLOSED'
    and c.secondaryclaimstatus = 'CLOSED'
    and patientclaimstatus = 'CLOSED')
and (c.primaryoutstanding = 0
    and c.secondaryoutstanding = 0
    and c.patientoutstanding = 0))`

Comment: I think now is correct the way you wrote it.

Comment: unfortunately it's still pulling back providers that have claims that have balances or claim statuses other than closed